# Google Custom Search API (CSE) - Retrieve only discussions

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

I would like to use the Google custom search API for searching only in discussions like using the query string `&tbm=dsc`.
Unfortunately there is no `tbm` parameter given in the API documentation.

Is it not possible to limit the search results to discussions only?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is currently not a way to do the discussion search with CSE/GSS. The only special search is `image` which is documented in the [API reference](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results). You could use Labels and [Refinements](http://support.google.com/customsearch//bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=topic&answer=2631064&topic=2642564) to limit your search to specific sites and/or patterns.

Answer (score 0):

**Limiting search results for Google Custom Search to only discussion websites is not possible.** Just in case, remember that [Google Custom Search is for searching over one website or a collection of websites.](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) If your collection is all discussion sites, well, that doesn't seem to be the purpose of Google Custom Search. However, there may be some useful workarounds/solutions.

**Workaround 0**

Find or generate a collection of discussion sites you're interest in and [create a custom search](http://www.google.com/cse/) based on that. This would accomplish (almost) the same results you are after.

**Workaround 1**

You might be able to perform a redirection with refinement labels. [This example redirects to a Google Scholar search.](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/queries#redirect) You might be able to accomplish the same result using `&tbm=dsc`.

```
<CustomSearchEngine>
  <Title>Universities</Title>
  <Context>
    <Facet>
      <FacetItem title="Papers">
        <Label name="papers" mode="FILTER"/>
        <Redirect url="http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=$q"/>
      </FacetItem>
    </Facet>
  </Context>
</CustomSearchEngine>
```